# Append auth_basic_user_file for specific location in Nginx

Tags: nginx

We have configured Nginx to use basic authentication for our entire site:

```
location / {
    # ... More stuff goes here ...

    # authentication
    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/conf.d/.htpasswd;
}
```

Now under a specific location, say `/x`, I'd like to allow all users defined in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/.htpasswd` as well as some additional users defined in another password file. I.e. something like this (which doesn't work):

```
location /x {  
    # authentication
    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/conf.d/.htpasswd, /etc/nginx/conf.d/.otherhtpasswd;
}
```

How can I achieve this with Nginx?

Comment: Was asked on ServerFault (https://serverfault.com/questions/817876/use-multiple-password-files-for-nginx) with no answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `nginx` does not accept multiple to the `auth_basic_user_file` directive, I would create a simple script to concat the two files into a 3rd file. Then reference that file with the `auth_basic_user_file` directive. You can then put that in a cron job or just run it every time one of the files changes.